# Class changing problem in email template in gmail and other provider

Tags: html, css, email

I have a email template. There I added table with class.

```
<table class="outer-table">
```

But when email has sent to inbox there is showing extra prefix with my class.

```
<table class="m_-297643930586757837outer-table">
```

In different email service there is showing different prefix. This is happen in every class name. So can't fix css issue.

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: It suppose that all styles should be inline... that means that you should'nt have classes in all html template... read: https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-coding/inline-css-in-html-emails/

Comment: In this case you can use [class*="outer-table"] {..} https://jsfiddle.net/7khvzm18/

Comment: Does this not get changed in your head <style> tags though to reflect the change - it shouldn't break anything as far as I'm aware.

What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @JGreatorex - style changes in different email service. and doesn't stay my written styles.

Comment: @ShahriyarAhmed - You able to provide the full HTML from the Email service?